# subclass of c_ubyte field in ctypes.BigEndianStructure becomes built-in type int

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to enrich the ctypes types with some methods, while being able to set the fields' values without a setter function. For c_ubyte/c_uint8 in a little endian Structure, the resulting field is an object of my subclass, as expected. In a big endian structure, the field becomes an int. Is this a bug in the implementation of ctypes (tried in 3.8 and 3.11)? How could I work around this with a custom metaclass?

```
import ctypes as ct


class MyUint16(ct.c_uint16):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class MyUint8(ct.c_uint8):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class MyStructBE(ct.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("f1", MyUint8),
                ("f2", MyUint16),]

class MyStructLE(ct.LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("f1", MyUint8),
                ("f2", MyUint16),]


s_le = MyStructLE()
s_le.f1 = 0x12
s_le.f2 = 0x1234
print(type(s_le.f1)) # <class '__main__.MyUint8'>
print(type(s_le.f2)) # <class '__main__.MyUint16'>
s_le.f1.foo()
s_le.f2.foo()


s_be = MyStructBE()
s_be.f1 = 0x12
s_be.f2 = 0x1234
print(type(s_be.f1)) # <class 'int'>    <-- Should be same as type(s_le.f1)
print(type(s_be.f2)) # <class '__main__.MyUint16'>
s_be.f1.foo()        # This won't work (AttributeError) 
s_be.f2.foo()
```

I know I could create a subclass from ctypes.Structure, but then I can't get/set the value without a getter/setter or accessing the 'value' field:

```
class Uint8(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("value", ctypes.c_ubyte)]
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class Uint16BE(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("value", ctypes.c_uint16)]
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("f1", Uint8),
                ("f2", Uint16BE),]

s_le = MyStruct()
s_le.f1 = 0x12       # TypeError: expected Uint8 instance, got int
s_le.f1.value = 0x12 # Want to avoid this
```